# $ \int_{0}^{1} x^{p}\left(\ln \frac{1}{x}\right)^{q} \mathrm{~d} x\;(p>0, q>0)$. Determine the convergence and divergence of it.

Tags: integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^{p}\left(\ln \frac{1}{x}\right)^{q} \mathrm{~d} x\quad(p>0, q>0) $$Determine the convergence and divergence of it. I have known that $\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x^p}\mathrm{~d} x$ is convergent when $p<1$ while it is divergent when $p\geq1$, but I have trouble connecting them.

Comment: Hint: Put $x=e^{-t}$.